# WPF TextBlock NoWrap shows two strings instead of one

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, nowrap

I have a problem with Run inside TextBlock

When I create TextBlock with no wrapping like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="_window">
    <Grid>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="100">
      <Run Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=_window}"/>
      </TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And assign Value very long string like `new string('-', (int) 1e6)`, it shows two lines insted of one.

What should I do to prevent it and to get exactly one line?

P.S. I cant use TextBlock without Run

Answer (score 0):

Use Text instead.

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="100" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=_window}"/>
```

Also you can use TextBlock as inline

```
<TextBlock Width="100">
    <Span FontSize="50">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=_window}"/>
    </Span>
    <Span FontSize="20">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=_window}"/>
    </Span>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: No, I cant use smiple TextBlock, because i need to highlight text

Comment: @PG_LoLo you can use TextBlock as inline, instead of Run. I've updated answer above, take a look.

Comment: Ok, i'll think about this trick, but why <Run> doesnt work correct?

Comment: @PG_LoLo I wish I could give you an explanation :) It seems like it's a bug, not sure.